# JQuery: Open/Close Menu, Opens but doesn't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'm trying to do a menu that hides on the left side and when we click on the button it opens or closes. I have the following code but the menu just opens, the code for closing isn't working, someone have a clue about what I did wrong?

```js
var menu = function() {

  /* Open Menu*/

  $('.js_open_seta').click(function() {
    $('.js_menu').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 200);

    $(".js_open_seta").addClass("js_close_seta");
    $(".js_open_seta").removeClass("js_open_seta");
    
  });

  /* Close Menu*/

  $('.js_close_seta').click(function() {
    $('.js_menu').animate({
      left: "-240px"
    }, 200);

    $(".js_close_seta").addClass("js_open_seta");
    $(".js_close_seta").removeClass("js_close_seta");

  });

};

$(document).ready(menu);
```

```css
body{
 background: url("imagens/exp.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 1280px 800px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

.js_menu{
 background: #4d4d4d;
 top: 0px;
 left: -240px;
 position: fixed;
   width: 310px;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 color: #ffffff;
 z-index: 50;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
}

#js_exp, #js_open{
 float: left;
 background:  #4d4d4d;
 height: 100%;
}

#js_exp{
 width: 240px;
}

#js_open{
 border-left: #ff0000;
 width: 70px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#js_seta{
 margin-top: 325px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
}
```

```html
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <nav class="js_menu">
   <section id="js_exp">
    <a href="#">SMPC</a>
    <a href="#">NGC Informática(2015)</a>
    <a href="#">NGC Informática (2015-2016)</a>
   </section>

   <section id="js_open">
    <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/ladygaga/images/4/40/Seta.png/revision/latest?cb=20110522223038&path-prefix=pt" class="js_open_seta" id="js_seta"/>
   </section>
   
  </nav>
   
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var menu = function() {


    $('#js_seta').click(function() {

    var check = $("#js_seta").hasClass("js_open_seta");        

        if(check) {
            $('.js_menu').animate({
                left: "0px"
            }, 200);

            $(".js_open_seta").addClass("js_close_seta");
            $(".js_open_seta").removeClass("js_open_seta");

        } else {
            $('.js_menu').animate({
                left: "-240px"
            }, 200);

            $(".js_close_seta").addClass("js_open_seta");
            $(".js_close_seta").removeClass("js_close_seta");

        }

    });

};


$(document).ready(menu);
```

This works

Comment: Yes that is the solution of course :)  … Mine was just an idea. As i said, i am not an expert.

Comment: I'm just a beginner so i appreciate all the help i get